# How can I print n statements each having variable using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd 
s2=pd.Series([1,2,34,5])  
s3=pd.Series(range(4))
s4=pd.Series([7,5,6,2.7,3,6,5,8,9])            
s5=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6],index=['a','$','@','4',"**",'^^'])             
s7=pd.Series(77,index=[1,2,3])                 
s8=pd.Series(1,index=range(5))              
s9=pd.Series('bello!',index=['a','d'])
```

Now I want to print all these at once using a loop or any other code. But when I tried doing it I was not able to put 's' and number together.

```
for i in range(2,10):
    print('s'+str(i))
```

This would print just 's1...' not the Series I want.

Any answer would be helpful..

Comment: `for s in [s2, s3, s4, s5, s7, s8, s9]: print(s)`?

Comment: In general when you find yourself naming variables with sequential numbers like that, you should be using a list instead of separate variables.

Comment: `print(locals().get('s'+str(i)))`

Comment: @Barmar I was just practicing different ways of using Series. But I will surely keep it in mind